# Which function satisfy $\ln(Y)=\int \ln(\exp(f(x)))\,dx$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $Y=\int\exp(f(x))\,dx$, as Michael, Surb pointed out that $\ln(Y)=\int\ln(\exp(f(x)) \, dx)=\int f(x) \, dx$ was not true.

However, what function in general would satisfy the expression of the form $\ln(\int\exp(f(x)) dx)=\int \ln(\exp(f(x)))\,dx$

Comment: This is not true: $\displaystyle \ln \int \exp(f(x)) \, dx$ is not usually the same as $\displaystyle \int \ln(\exp(f(x))) \, dx. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy but we use $\int e^{f(x)} dx = e^{\int f(x) dx}$, if that was not true, then how could it be?

Comment: I changed $\exp^{f(x)}$ to $\exp(f(x)).$ The whole point of the $\exp$ notation is to make it unnecessary to use a superscript when the exponent looks long and complicated. Thus $\displaystyle e^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k)}$ is the same as $ \displaystyle \exp\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k) \right)$ except that the latter is typographically more felicitous.

Comment: It is not true that $\displaystyle \int e^{f(x)} \, dx$ is the same as $e^{ \int f(x)\,dx}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you. Do you know in which condition $f(x)$ would satisfy the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem convinced that
$$
\exp\biggl(\,\int f(x)\,dx\biggr)=\int e^{f(x)}\,dx
$$
(for some determination of the integrations constants).

Suppose so. After differentiating, we obtain
$$
f(x)\exp\biggl(\,\int f(x)\,dx\biggr)=e^{f(x)}
$$
by the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Differentiating again, with $G(x)=\exp(\int f(x)\,dx)$,
$$
f'(x)G(x)+(f(x))^2G(x)=f'(x)e^{f(x)}=f'(x)f(x)G(x)
$$
Removing $G(x)$ that must be nonzero (why?), we get that $f$ is a solution of the differential equation
$$
(1-y)y'+y^2=0
$$
which admits separation of variables:
$$
\frac{y-1}{y^2}\,dy=dx
$$
so we get
$$
\frac{1}{y}+\log\lvert y\rvert=x+c
$$
Certainly not all functions satisfy this equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct !

Take $f(x)=x$. Then $$Y=\int_0^1 e^{f(x)} \, dx=e-1,$$
but $$\ln(Y)=\ln(e-1)\neq \int_0^1 x \, dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$